# Show a splash screen with MvvmCross after Android purged an application from memory

Tags: android, mvvmcross

Here is my scenario: when my app gets purged from memory by the OS and its reopened from the recent apps list, it goes straight to the Activity that was last open. When this happens I would like to initialize a couple of business objects.

My first approach to achieve this was to do the initialization in the `InitializeLastChance` method in the `Setup` class. 
Inside the `InitializeLastChance` method I check if the current top activity is the `MvxSplashScreenActivity`. If it's not, I make the necessary initialization. The code is something like this:

```
protected override void InitializeLastChance()
{           
    try
    {
        var topActivity = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity;
        if (topActivity.LocalClassName != _splashScreenName)
        {
            //Do special initialization
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log error
    }

    base.InitializeLastChance();
}
```

This works as expected but the visual effect isn't the best: a blank screen with the name of the app appears for a couple of seconds while the initialization occurs. When the initialization is finished, the last open activity is loaded.

To avoid this blank screen, I wanted to try a different approach: show an Activity while the initialization is being done, similar to a splash screen, so that the user can have some feedback that something is happening. In this approach the ViewModel attached to the new Activity would do the initialization that I want. 
To show this new activity, I tried creating a custom `IMvxAppStart` and register it in the `App` class, but that hasn't worked. My custom `IMvxAppStart` has the following code:

```
public class CustomAppStart
       : MvxNavigatingObject
       , IMvxAppStart
    {
        public void Start(object hint = null)
        {            
            if (hint == null)
            {              
                ShowViewModel<LoginViewModel>();
            }
            else
            {
                ShowViewModel<InitializationViewModel>();
            }
        }
    }
```

I wanted to show the `LoginViewModel` when the app starts from scratch and in the cases where the app goes straight to the last loaded Activity, the `InitializationViewModel` would be shown. In the latter scenario the Start method isn't called. I've checked the MvvmCross source code and as far as I can understand, the Start method is called by the `MvxSplashScreenActivity` (correct me if I'm wrong). When an app is reopened and goes straight to the last opened Activity, the `MvxSplashScreenActivity` isn't used so the Start method in `CustomAppStart` is not called.

That being said, I have some questions regarding the `CustomAppStart` approach:

1. Is this approach the best way to show a splash screen or "initialization activity" in the cases where the app goes straight to the last opened activity?
2. How do I use the `CustomAppStart` in these situations, since it seems that the Start method is called only from the `MvxSplashScreenActivity`?
3. How do I pass a value to the hint parameter in the Start method?

Thanks

Comment: This is hard to fight against - as the setup is actually being called from the OnCreate of your reinflated Activity... One way to tackle this is to put minimal functionality in the `Setup` and to also give all your Activities a `theme` - this `theme` will get drawn before the `Create` happens (it's how the default Mvx splashscreen is drawn)

Comment: Thanks @Stuart, I'll follow your suggestion. I'll give a theme to all Activities so that the theme is drawn when an Activity is reinflated. That way at least the user gets some feedback.

Comment: @DuarteSilva did you managed to find a solution other than theme?

Comment: @Nikola, no I didn't find another solution. I went with the theme suggestion because it was the best I could find